# App not supported in Android Market for samsung tab 2 - GT-P3100 tablet

Tags: android

I am creating an application only for tablets (7 and 10.1 inch). I put below the code in my android manifest file:         I put my app in Android market. But it's not showing up in my Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1. In that support device is only 7 inch Tablets. I want my app for both 7 inch and 10.1 inch but samsung galxt tab2-GT-P3100  is unsupported device in google play . Please, some one help me to solve this problem.